# sorting arrays in C++

Tags: c++

**1.**

```
const int nSize=6;
int anArray[nSize]={ 30, 60, 20, 50, 40, 10 };
for(int nStartIndex=0;nStartIndex<nSize;nStartIndex++)
{
    int nSmallestIndex=nStartIndex;

    for(int nCurrentIndex=nStartIndex+1;nCurrentIndex<nSize;nCurrentIndex++)
    {
        if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nStartIndex])
            nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;
    }

    swap(anArray[nStartIndex],anArray[nSmallestIndex]);


}
```

**2.**

```
const int nSize=6;
int anArray[nSize]={ 30, 60, 20, 50, 40, 10 };
for(int nStartIndex=0;nStartIndex<nSize;nStartIndex++)
{
    int nSmallestIndex=nStartIndex;

    for(int nCurrentIndex=nStartIndex+1;nCurrentIndex<nSize;nCurrentIndex++)
    {
        if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nSmallestIndex])
            nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;
    }

    swap(anArray[nStartIndex],anArray[nSmallestIndex]);


}
```

why do they give different results although nSmallestIndex equals to nStartIndex?

first code results `{10,30,20,40,50,60}`

second code results `{10,20,30,40,50,60}`

Comment: You should run this in a debugger, or add print statements, in order to track the values of the variables over time.  Then you would see that they're not the same.

Comment: Because `nSmallestIndex` is not always the same as `nStartIndex`. That's why you get a difference. See: `nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic in code sampe 1 is wrong and that's why it gives the wrong answer. In your second loop, you want to find the smallest element from [nStartIndex, nSize). But you only compare the current one with anArray[nStartIndex]. At the end you get nSmallestIndex equal to the last element smaller than anArray[nStartIndex].

For code sample two, the logic is right. You save the current smallest index in nSmallestIndex and use the updated version to compare in the if statement,

```
   if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nSmallestIndex])
```

btw, the sorting method in this code is O(N^2) which is not good generally. It is also noted by others here C++ STL has facilities to do this better and portable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and answer, I am at the learning process so I'm trying to learn algorithm in addition to C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrong condition inside your inner loop in the first example: `if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nStartIndex])`. Use `nSmallestIndex` instead of `nStartIndex`.

But in `C++` you can do it in one line:

```
std::sort( anArray, anArray + nSize, std::less<int>() );
```

If you want to do it in `C` just use this code:

```
const int nSize=6;
int anArray[nSize]={ 30, 60, 20, 50, 40, 10 };

int Compare(const void* a ,const void* b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a > *(int*)b ) ? 1 : ( ( *(int*)a < *(int*)b ) ? -1 : 0 );
}

...

qsort( anArray, nSize, sizeof( int ), &Compare );
```

Comment: @JurajBlaho: I don't the original author is asking for a better way to sort (this sort algorithm is O(N^2)). He/She is trying to ask what's wrong with his/her code logically.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I pointed where the bug in his code is.

Comment: _"Use nSmallestIndex instead of nStartIndex"_ don't you think it will make **1** same as **2** What's the point the ?

Comment: @POW: yes, it will. The first example just won't work as expected.

Comment: @SergeyK. exactly and this is question "**why** do they give different results" ?

Answer (score 0):

Because nSmallestIndex equals to nStartIndex only at the begining of the second for, after some iteration nSmallestIndex can change but nSmallestIndex won't change because there are not the same variable

Comment: Only this answer tries to respond to OP's "why" question.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind selection sort is to find the smallest/largest element and position it to a proper index

Clearly your first algo's inner for loop

```
for(int nCurrentIndex=nStartIndex+1;nCurrentIndex<nSize;nCurrentIndex++)
    {
        if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nStartIndex])
            nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;
    }
```

Never compares with new smaller index, it just compares the iterating number with original smaller value.

Whereas in 2nd algo's inner loop

```
for(int nCurrentIndex=nStartIndex+1;nCurrentIndex<nSize;nCurrentIndex++)
    {
        if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nSmallestIndex])
            nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;
    }
```

It updates the `smallestIndex` and hence correctly find the smallest value for a swap.

Comment: I'll surely remove my answer if down voters can explain please

Comment: I will do the same too. I don't know why these people voted down yours and mine which are similar. But I think there is something wrong here.

Comment: The first example in the question is wrong.

Comment: @SergeyK. Yes and is explained why in my post

Answer (score 0):

> why do they give different results although nSmallestIndex equals to nStartIndex?

The only difference betweent the two pieces of code:

```
<         if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nStartIndex])
---
>         if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[nSmallestIndex])
```

So the conditional is different on `nSmallestIndex` and `nStartIndex`. But these values are not the same in the two pieces of code:

See the lines:

```
    if(anArray[nCurrentIndex]<anArray[<VALUE>])
        nSmallestIndex=nCurrentIndex;
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Assignment changes the value.
```